# $\langle u| \langle v| A |u\rangle |v\rangle \geq 0$ for any $|u\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_1$ and $|v\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_2$. Then $A$ is Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

$\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ are complex Hilbert spaces. $A$ is an operator from $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes \mathcal{H}_2$ to $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes \mathcal{H}_2$.

Suppose that $\langle u| \langle v| A |u\rangle |v\rangle \geq 0$ for any vectors $|u\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_1$ and
$|v\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_2$. Then $A$ is Hermitian.

The source of the above statement is M . Horodecki, P. Horodecki, and R. Horodecki, “On the necessary and sufficient conditions for separability of mixed quantum states” (e-print archive: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9605038) [image]
Attempt of Proof.

$\langle u|\langle v| A |u\rangle |v\rangle  \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\langle u|\langle v| A |u\rangle |v\rangle =(\langle u|\langle v| A |u\rangle |v\rangle )^* = \langle u|\langle v| A^{\dagger} |u\rangle |v\rangle  $
$\langle u|\langle v| A-A^{\dagger} |u\rangle |v\rangle  = 0 $ for any $|u\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_1$ and
$|v\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_2$.

Now I am lost how to proceed to show that $A = A^{\dagger} $. 
Any hints or references are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It will look better if you use \langle and \rangle

Comment: Use $\langle$ and $\rangle$ for nicer-looking ketbras.

Comment: The \langle \rangle fairy is here to save the day!

Comment: mvpq, kimchi lover, Patric Stevens Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using Remark 1, by chance? Also, to tag someone on a question/answer that isn't theirs, you must use the @ in front of their name, such as @someone.

Comment: @CameronBuie Actually I think what I am trying to prove is equivalent to remark1.

Comment: I believe that you're correct. Since you included it in the post, though, I assumed that it was a hint toward proving the given claim.

Comment: A way to directly use remark 1: it suffices to show that real linear combinations of matrices of the form $P \otimes Q$ gives us every Hermitian matrix (and therefore every rank-1 Hermitian matrix)

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:** For an arbitrary Hermitian operator $M$, there exist projections $P_j,Q_j$ and real coefficients $a_j$ such that
$$
M = \sum_{j}a_j P_j \otimes Q_j.
$$
**Proof of Claim:** Note that $M$ can be written in the form $M = \sum_p A_p \otimes B_p$, where $A_p,B_p$ are Hermitian matrices (this can be proven formally, but it is easy to see in terms of matrices if we take $\{A_p\}$ to be a nice (sparse) basis of the Hermitian matrices).  Moreover, we can write $A_p = \sum_q a_{pq} P_q$ for real coefficients $a_{pq}$ (for instance, using a spectral decomposition) and similarly $B_p = \sum_{q}b_{pq}Q_q$.  With that have
$$
\begin{align}
M &= \sum_p A_p \otimes B_p = \sum_{pq} a_{pq}b_{pq}\,A_{pq} \otimes B_{pq}.
\quad \square
\end{align}
$$
Now, we can prove the result as follows: suppose that $M$ is an operator satisfying $\operatorname{Tr}(M(P \otimes Q)) \geq 0$ for all projections $P,Q$.  To show that $M$ is Hermitian, it suffices to show that for any $w \in \mathcal H_1 \otimes \mathcal H_2$, we have $w^*Mw \in \Bbb R$.  Because $ww^* \in L(\mathcal H_1 \otimes \mathcal H_2)$ is a Hermitian operator, there exist real coefficients $a_j$ such that 
$$
ww^* = \sum_{j} a_j P_j \otimes Q_j.
$$
It follows that
$$
w^*Mw = \operatorname{Tr}(M ww^*) = 
\operatorname{Tr}\left(M \sum_{j}a_j P_j \otimes Q_j\right)
= \sum_j a_j \operatorname{Tr}(M(P_j \otimes Q_j)) \in \Bbb R
$$
as desired.

Comment: For a more direct proof, note that $A$ is Hermitian if and only if we have $\langle w|A|w \rangle \in \Bbb R$ for all $|w \rangle \in \mathcal H$.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot see how $\langle w_1 + \alpha w_2|A|w_1 + \alpha w_2 \rangle \geq 0$ follows from the hypothesis that $\langle u| \langle v| A |u\rangle |v\rangle \geq 0$

Comment: You're right; I made a pretty big error there.  I'll try to salvage the proof

Comment: See my latest edit.